# How to get random values from an object and display cleanly as HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

My question is related to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671586/get-random-x-items-from-array-in-javascript)
I have a javascript array and I select four random items from it:

```
function getRandomObjects(array,selected,needed){
    /*
     *@param array array The array to pull from
     *@param selected array The array of results pulled so far
     *@param needed int The number of results we want
     */
    var length = array.length;
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * length) + 1; // get random number in bounds of array
    var exists=false; // make sure we didnt already pick this object
    $.each(selected,function(i,obj){
        if(obj.index==num)exists=true;
    })
    if(exists) getRandomObjects(array,selected,needed); // get a new one if this was a duplicate
    else selected.push(array[num]);
    if(selected.length!=needed) return getRandomObjects(array,selected,needed); // get another object if we need more
    else return selected; // return the final result set
}




var testData = [
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a90c4206b128cd8654",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "1f3269fc-0822-4c5a-9c52-8055155b407e",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,026.95",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a9a986ccb2f41cf7b9",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "a6b726b6-6466-4e48-8697-1c6bd7b1c79e",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,642.74",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a9f98f8b2f6880de32",
    "index": 2,
    "guid": "e7d736cc-19e0-4bcb-8d0a-4d17442d8cee",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,341.64",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a9e40ded5b017e45cd",
    "index": 3,
    "guid": "64230ca8-05c0-4c39-a931-794172475a32",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,196.13",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a90cc30be769a06d7c",
    "index": 4,
    "guid": "d6618b78-753a-4ad0-bc14-3687d0b99196",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,611.62",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a92481a43f50607415",
    "index": 5,
    "guid": "35ec8186-9494-4f89-ab89-bed7f39872c3",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,148.87",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a9164f17c558ba7ce1",
    "index": 6,
    "guid": "244970a0-1ce2-405a-8d69-c7903f9bf5eb",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$3,758.13",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a95afde31c5cf592a8",
    "index": 7,
    "guid": "aa30c82d-dd2b-420c-8b30-7d66cec8d10b",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,311.40",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  }
]


var randomObjects=getRandomObjects(testData,[],4);

console.log(randomObjects);
```

But I do not want to show the raw code to the console. I want to show each item with its values as clean HTML. I thought I could do this by making a variation to the last line of the above code like so:

```
<p id="test></p>
```

Then:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = randomObjects;
```

But that doesn't work,I don't get my items in HTML rather I get this:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Help please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't render objects, i.e., arrays, in the DOM, you need to turn it into a string first.

```js
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(randomObjects);
```

Comment: Doesn't work ... error message
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#134:50'>134:50</a> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use **pre** tag to show better output in browser HTML.

```js
function getRandomObjects(array,selected,needed){
    /*
     *@param array array The array to pull from
     *@param selected array The array of results pulled so far
     *@param needed int The number of results we want
     */
    var length = array.length;
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * length) + 1; // get random number in bounds of array
    var exists=false; // make sure we didnt already pick this object
    $.each(selected,function(i,obj){
        if(obj.index==num)exists=true;
    })
    if(exists) getRandomObjects(array,selected,needed); // get a new one if this was a duplicate
    else selected.push(array[num]);
    if(selected.length!=needed) return getRandomObjects(array,selected,needed); // get another object if we need more
    else return selected; // return the final result set
}




var testData = [
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a90c4206b128cd8654",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "1f3269fc-0822-4c5a-9c52-8055155b407e",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,026.95",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a9a986ccb2f41cf7b9",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "a6b726b6-6466-4e48-8697-1c6bd7b1c79e",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,642.74",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a9f98f8b2f6880de32",
    "index": 2,
    "guid": "e7d736cc-19e0-4bcb-8d0a-4d17442d8cee",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,341.64",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a9e40ded5b017e45cd",
    "index": 3,
    "guid": "64230ca8-05c0-4c39-a931-794172475a32",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,196.13",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a90cc30be769a06d7c",
    "index": 4,
    "guid": "d6618b78-753a-4ad0-bc14-3687d0b99196",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,611.62",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a92481a43f50607415",
    "index": 5,
    "guid": "35ec8186-9494-4f89-ab89-bed7f39872c3",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,148.87",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a9164f17c558ba7ce1",
    "index": 6,
    "guid": "244970a0-1ce2-405a-8d69-c7903f9bf5eb",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$3,758.13",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  },
  {
    "_id": "57e5d1a95afde31c5cf592a8",
    "index": 7,
    "guid": "aa30c82d-dd2b-420c-8b30-7d66cec8d10b",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$1,311.40",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
  }
]


var randomObjects=getRandomObjects(testData,[],4);
console.log(JSON.stringify(randomObjects));
$(document).ready(function(){$("#test").html(JSON.stringify(randomObjects, undefined, 1))})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="test"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this code with your own code.

```js
var lengthOfArray = array.length;
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * lengthOfArray);
var keys = Object.keys(array[randomNum]); // Get the objects in the ARRAY
return array[randomNum][keys[(keys.length * Math.random()) << 0]]; // Get the random item in the object
```